# Webpack and Phaser 3 configuration

Tags: javascript, webpack, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a game using phaser 3 from a book tutorial and I decided to include webpack for learning purposes. I'm just in the initial stage of the game creation but when I ran the `npm start` script I got many errors that I fixed one by one. I don't have more errors but when running the scrip I got a blank page and nothing in being created in my dist folder. This is my webpack.config.js file content:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },

  // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  // https://webpack.js.org/concepts/plugins/
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets', '**', '*'),
          to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        },
      ],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'typeof CANVAS_RENDERER': JSON.stringify(true),
      'typeof WEBGL_RENDERER': JSON.stringify(true),
    }),
  ],
};
```

And the rest of the files are located in my [repo](https://github.com/fabricio-garcia/phaser-game/tree/feature/phase-1), feel free to check it out. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change line in CopyWebpackPlugin

from `from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets', '**', '*'),`

to `from: 'src/assets',`

2. then `npm run build`

Comment: I did that, no errors but still getting a blank page

Comment: However, I notice when running `npm run build` the files are generated in `dist/`, then if I `run npm start` everything in the `dist/` folder is removed.

Comment: npm run start - make 'virtual build' in memory
npm run build - make real build in disk

I see other errors in project, if i find time, i try to help

Comment: No worries, I manage to drive the problem just now.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by creating a base and prod webpack files for better code readability and also importing every image that I need for the game in every scene. The most challenging part was the prod.js file because I was able to render images using npm start but not npm run build.